# Unable to read file in excelJS

Tags: exceljs

Hey there so i have used the excel JS CDN link to try and read a template test.xlsx file
I keep getting this error

I tried adding the relative path and the current path but both exist on same level and yet I'm unable to do the readFile Operation on excelJS
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtRZl.png);
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6aGa.png)